# Command setup:di:compile error for Repositories code

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We have developed one **Magento2** Website **Version - 2.2.1**, in every instance - Production, Staging and Local facing the same issue as:

Error while running **`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`**

Repositories code generation breaks every time in **14%** or **1/7 instance**.

```
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 56.0 MiB
```

[image]

Comment: Can error log ..

Comment: no error on log.

Comment: just run this and see what error you get ?
php bin/magento

Comment: no error by this command

Comment: can you run with this command:
php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: yes i used with memory limit also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you would like it as a method but try to remove all modules in

> app/code

(especially remove the modules added recently , the last time you remember the compile went fine ) .

There might be an issue on an __construct you have called on one of those modules. 
Add the modules one by one .
Test on the local/dev site first.

After removing the modules , dont forget to do :

```
rm -rf var/generation/*
```

Comment: Okay let me try this

Comment: i have checked with disable all modules, same issue

Comment: not to disable , to remove them.

Comment: Yes, It is working now. Thanks for Valuable answer.

Comment: Im happy it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

check in your code

use Magento\Tests\NamingConvention\true\string;

can break your s:d:c